# How to explain the Gath-Geva algorithm for Gaussian mixture models intuitively?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, intuition

I have used the Gath-Geva algorithm for my geophysical research. One of the reviewers responded that he does not understand the algorithm and asked for a flow chart. What should I do? I have explained the algorithm in detail using formulas, but the comment is that the explanation is not sufficient.
My text:

```
The Gath-Geva algorithm is an extension of Gustafson-Kessel algorithm that takes the size and
density of the clusters into account. In contrast to fuzzy-c-means algorithm and the Gustafson-
Kessel algorithm, the Gath-Geva algorithm is not based on an objective function, but is a
fuzzification of statistical estimators. Deteailed mathematical description is given in Wolfe (1970)
and Gath and Geva(1989), only intuitive explanation of expectation maximization algorithms will
be given (GG belongs to the family of expectation maximization algorithms). The Expectation-
Maximization (EM) algorithm is a general algorithm for maximum-likelihood estimation where the
data are “incomplete” or the likelihood function involves latent variables (Zhai, 2007).It isimportant to note that the notion of “incomplete data” and “latent variables” are related: when we
have a latent variable, we may regard our data as being incomplete since we do not observe values
of the latent variables; similarly, when our data are incomplete, we often can also associate some
latent variable with the missing data.
Each iteration of the EM algorithm consistsof two processes: The E-step, and the M-step. In the
expectation, or E-step, the hidden(latent) data are estimated given the observed data and current
estimate of the model parameters. This is achieved using the conditional expectation. In the M-step,
the likelihood function is maximized under the assumption that the hidden data are known. The
estimate of the hidden data from the E-step are used rather than the actual hidden data. Convergence
is assured since the algorithm is guaranteed to increase the likelihood at each iteration. The EM
algorithm is a hill-climbing approach, thus it can only be guanranteed to reach a local maxima.
When there are multiple maximas, whether we will actually reach the global maxima clearly
depends on where we start; if we start at the “right hill”, we will be able to find a global maxima.
(Zhai,2007). With EM we infer that our data is composed of multiple multivariate normal
distributions. It is very strong assumption especially that we set the number of clusters in advance.
```

Atter that I have copied 4 formulas from Gath-Geva paper,mean,posterior probability itd.
What should I change?

Comment: Can you provide the explanation you already tried? (Ie, your formulas, etc.)

Comment: @gang Will try.